# App crash in IBAction method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Okay, so here is my code

```
-(IBAction)nextAction
{
    dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{ [self plusOneDate]; });
}

-(void)plusOneDate
{
    int hoursToAdd = 1;  

    // set up date components
    NSDateComponents *components = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
    [components setHour:hoursToAdd];

    // create a calendar
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
    NSDate *newDate2 = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:appStateDate options:0];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYYMMddHH0000"];
    dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:newDate2];
    [formatter release];

    appStateDate = newDate2;
    newDate2 = nil;
}
```

All it does is it adds 1 hour to a NSDate object (appStateDate), formats it, and sets the dateString variable.

Every time I press the UIButton in the app, connected to `nextAction`, the app crashes.
I tried deleting the xib file and creating a new one. It did not help, and still crashes.

In debug mode:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '(null): unrecognized selector sent to class 0x6242690'
```

Anyone who know why? I'm getting frustrated.

Comment: Why don't you use the debugger to find at exactly which step the app crashes?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this syntax `^{ [self plusOneDate]; }`. Are you sure that's Ok.?

Comment: That's Objective-C 2.0 block syntax. Think anonymous closures. It's available in Apple's GCC, as well as the clang compiler (for everyone).

Comment: @Noam -- it's a block. They're new. It's correct syntax.

Comment: In the debugger, you can find out which object crashed given its address, in this case 0x6242690. In the debugger console, type `po 0x6242690` and it will print the description of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an answer so much as it is an observation.  The value assigned to appStateDate at the end of the method is an autoreleased object, and nowhere are you retaining it.  You cannot rely on the "retain" attribute of the property (if appStateDate is in fact declared as a property somewhere), because you didn't use the property in the assignment.

As soon as that IBAction finishes, the object pointed to by appStateDate is going to be reclaimed when the runloop drains the NSAutoreleasePool.  Perhaps that's where the crash is coming from.