# compare two NSDate fails

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios

I try to compare two NSDate objects.
But it fails all the time and I can not see what is wrong.

```
  -(IBAction)nextAction
{
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    if([appStateDate compare:today] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        dispatch_async(calcQueue, ^{ [self plusOneDate]; });
    }
}
```

Without the code it works fine.

it just crashes, and EXE_BAD_ACCESS on this line in the main method.

```
 int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

And prints

```
'+[ compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x634d7e0`'
```

Im not good at using the debugger, so if you know any good tutorials or guides i like to know them to ;)  sorry for my english

Comment: after searching everywhere for how to compare whether a date was before some other date, very happy I came across your question to learn the proper code if([firstDate compare:secondDate] == NSOrderedAscending) { //secondDate is after firstDate } else { //firstDate is after secondDate }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like appStateDate is not initialized, or contains something other than a NSDate.  Where do you intitialize it?

Comment: its intitialize in the viewDidLoad. [NSDate date];

Comment: There you go. `[NSDate date]` produces an autoreleased object - once viewDidLoad returns, it's released. To make it persist between events, either use `[[NSDate alloc] init]`, or `[retain]` it.

Answer (score 2):

to compares 2 `NSDate` dates:

```
NSDate *date1; NSDate *date2;
if ([date1 timeIntervalSinceDate:date2] > 0) 
    // date1 is newer.
```

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128054/app-crash-in-ibaction-method) topic, I would say like @Seva-Alekseyev, in *-(IBAction)nextAction*, appStateDate doesn't look like it's declared/initialized.

Maybe you should write what you already have in your *-(void)plusOneDate*  method.

Just to check, you can also NSLog the type of variable and the value of *appStateDate* to see if it is what it's supposed to be.

I'm a beginner too, I'm not sure, but just trying to help :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I strongly suggest you to look at the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) to get a better knowledge of memory management.

It appears to me that `appStateDate` is not longer instance of `NSDate` class due to the way you are allocating it. When you use `[NSDate date]` you are actually saying `[[[NSDate alloc]init]autorelease]` so that object gets released before you can actually make use of it. Normally what you want to do with class instance objects is to `alloc` and `init` them, and then `release` them in the `dealloc` method.

I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

It was actually the today that was the problem. 
The memory addr was in the console and i hovered over the objects to find the one matching.
I just retained it, and released it in the end of the method.
Thanks for all your answers ;)